# ElasticSearch - Unique Tags for multiple documents (indexing)

Tags: elasticsearch

We would like a unique Tag and multiple values in elastic search : to be clearer. We need to do a timeserie graph. So we get values between 2 dates. But of course we have different kinds of data. That where our tags comes. We want to search our tags with an autoCompletion, then choose our values with the dates.

```
{tag :["sdfsf", "fddsfsd", "fsdfsf"]
  {
  values : 145.45
  date : "2004-10-23"
  },
  {
  values : 556.09
  date : "2010-02-13"
  }
}
```

After, a bit of research we found the parent/child technique but because we want to do a completion on tag (in the parent), we need an aggregation which is impossible in ES with "has_parent".

Our solutions is to do :

```
{
    {
    tag :["sdfsf", "fddsfsd", "fsdfsf"],
    values : 145.45,
    date : "2004-10-23"
    },
    {
    tag :null,
    values : 556.09,
    date : "2010-02-13"
    }, {etc...}
}
```

So we only have one tag easy to check with completion. But it's kind of "ugly".

Does anybody have a correct way to do what we want to do ?
thx in advance

Comment: I don't think parent/child is what you want, because "tags" are just a property on your record.  Could you please provide the queries that you want to run and what is failing on them.

Comment: Actually I know that parent/child isn't a good choice for this. My query is huge so sadly I won't put it there because it's not the solution and I understand why. What I would like is a new way/idea to not repeate my tags on each of my points.
But still thx for your reply

Comment: You said you "don't want to repeat my tags on each point". The idea behind ES and other no-SQL data stores is precisely that you DO want those repeated on each record. A completely different mindset is required compared to a SQL database.